# Cypress Test Coverage not instrumented

Tags: typescript, next.js, cypress, code-coverage

I have been struggling to get test coverage on e2e tests working with a Next.JS application.

I have created the base application with

```
yarn create next-app --typescript --eslint --experimental-app
```

Then I followed the [instrumentation documentation](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#instrument-your-application). Here is my setup:

- package.json (limited to essential)

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "cypress:e2e": "cypress open --e2e"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.21.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
        "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.10.0",
        "@types/cypress": "^1.1.3",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
        "cypress": "^12.8.1"
    }
}
```

- tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

- cypress.config.ts (limited to essential)

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
    env: {

    },

    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
            return config;
        },
    },
});
```

- .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "next/babel"],
    "plugins": ["istanbul"]
}
```

- cypress/support/e2e.ts

```
import './commands'
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

What happens is when I run the tests, it says the code is not instrumented:
[image: test not instrumented]

I have also tested with the `@bahmutov/cypress-code-coverage` package instead with similar result.